# Any way to add pdf report as an appendix in latex?

Tags: pdf, appendices, sharelatex

I have html report that generated by online software tools, whereas I intend to insert those report as an appendix in my latex project. I used online tools to convert html report to `pdf` first. However, I know how to add an appendix in latex, but adding independent pdf docs as latex appendix is unknown for me. How can I make this happen? Is there any shortcut to do this? How can I continue my latex preamble with latex code that could allow me to insert several pages of pdf doc as an appendix? Any idea please? Thaks in advance :)

Here is the url of `html` report:

[html report](http://bioconductor.org/spb_reports/CATALYST_buildreport_20170326074717.html)

Comment: I think `\includepdf` from the `pdfpages` package is what you need here then.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer what would be concrete latex code I could try? Could you extend your motivation please? Thank you :)

Comment: `\includepdf{mysupersophisticatedreport.pdf}`  ;-) If I remember correctly, the `.pdf` extension can be omitted, however

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Is that possible to add original `html` report as an appendix in latex? If I try your solution, where can I put `pdf` files in my latex project (I used `sharelatex`)?

Comment: I don't use such online 'tools' ... but I am pretty sure that they allow to upload `.pdf` files like for graphics, so you should be able to upload the converted `html` report. You can attach files to a `.pdf` file as will with `attachfile2`, the `.html` is then included in the `.pdf` file and be extracted ('saved') from that file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the given link by the OP and generated a `htmlreport.pdf` file from the `.html` document (just printing to file), in addition I saved the file (this provided two files, the `.html` and the `.css` file actually)

The `.pdf` file can be input in pieces or completely with `\includepdf`, the `.html` and `.css` file can be attached with `\attachfile` from `attachfile2` (please read the documentation of `attachfile` as well).

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{attachfile2}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Theory of Brontosaurs}

\chapter{How to become a brain surgeon}

\appendix

\includepdf[pages={3-5}]{htmlreport.pdf}

Source of report: \attachfile[color=blue,mimetype=text/html,icon={Paperclip},description={Source of report}]{reportsource.html}
Additional CSS file: \attachfile[color=blue,mimetype=text/css,icon={Paperclip},description={CSS of report}]{report.css}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Please have a look on the `embedfile` package as well!

Comment: so I don't need to make conversion between `html` and `pdf` right? your answer is quite interesting. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Dan: You can attach the `.html` file completely to the LaTeX output `.pdf` file without any conversion, yes, if you prefer do so. In this case you can omit the `\includepdf` statement, of course. I don't think that the `.html` file will be really large that any size restrictions are violated...